# Smooth animate hide and show Master View Controller in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation, uisplitviewcontroller

I am developing iPad application using `UISplitViewController`. I want to show/hide Master View Controller on demand. I have seen [How to hide & unhide Master View Controller in SplitView Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020323/how-to-hide-unhide-master-view-controller-in-splitview-controller) and [Animate visibility of master detail controller of UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526882/animate-visibility-of-master-detail-controller-of-uisplitviewcontroller), so I came up with something like this:

I have `hideMasterView` `BOOL` variable in my `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` and when I want to show/hide Master View I call:

```
hideMasterView = !hideMasterView;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                          [self.splitViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
                          [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
                          [self.splitViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
                          [self.splitViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews];
                          [self.splitViewController.view layoutSubviews];
                      }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

And my delegate has method:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
              inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    return hideMasterView;
}
```

It works, but animation is not quite smooth. On hide everything works fine, but **when Master View is being shown, Detail View is resized before sliding, leaving blank gray space on right and sliding on it afterwards**.

How to fix this animation?